# I'm trying to run app on release mode but these errors doesn’t allow me?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods, solver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDHxg.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tlHN.jpg)

I have just update my pod file, and run flutter clean cmd and again install pod file.
and one of example shows to delete pod lock file and again install pod is that right to do??
let me know how to resolve this error.